# How do I get to the wiki?

Tags: support, privileges

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki

How do I actually get to the wiki so that I can edit it?  I received the alert bar across the top on stackoverflow.com with "You can now edit the Wiki!", but, I don't see a link for "Wiki" for me to edit anywhere on stackoverflow.com

Much respect, but, usability fail.

Answer (score 3):

Community Wiki posts are not separate; rather, they are posts which the author has marked as `community wiki`. These posts are designed to allow as many people to contribute as possible without allowing spammers in.

Community Wiki posts can be identified because they do not display an avatar; furthermore, you will see an `edit` link even though they are not your on posts.

The option to make posts community wiki is a small checkbox in the lower right when answering questions—however, only check this box when sure, as you will not receive reputation.

[FAQ for Community Wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Answer (score 1):

In the search bar enter

`wiki:1`

This will display all community wikis.

An example of community wikis are the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki:1+[faq]).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a Wikipedia-type site that you can edit. It's referring to Community Wiki posts. You're allowed to edit them once you hit 100 reputation.

See [What are community wiki posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) for more information.